# Diff multidimensional dictionaries in python

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries

```
a = {'home': {'name': 'Team1', 'score': 0}, 'away': {'name': 'Team2', 'score': 0}}
b = {'home': {'name': 'Team1', 'score': 2}, 'away': {'name': 'Team2', 'score': 0}}
```

The keys never change but I want to get that ['home']['score'] has changed

Any easy way to do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to do? I want to give it a try :)

Comment: Why not encapsulate the values into a seperate class?

Comment: I'm looking to compare two dictionaries and find out which key is the key that changed.. so in the example b['home']['score'] changed from 0 to 2 so I want to know that it was ['home']['score'] that has changed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715234/python-dict-update-diff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a knee-jerk initial response:

```
a = {'home': {'name': 'Team1', 'score': 0}, 'away': {'name': 'Team2', 'score': 0}}
b = {'home': {'name': 'Team1', 'score': 2}, 'away': {'name': 'Team2', 'score': 0}}

def valchange(d1, d2, parent=''):
    changes=[]
    for k in d1.keys():
        if type(d1[k])==type({}):
            changes.extend(valchange(d1[k], d2[k], k))
        else:
            if d1[k]!=d2[k]:
                if parent=='':
                    changes.append(k + ' has changed ')
                else:
                    changes.append(parent + '.' + k + ' has changed')
    return changes

print valchange(a,b)

>>>
['home.score has changed']
```

Comment: Note the use of `<>` is equivalent to `!=`.  The standard has changed since this was posted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use my package that is for python:
https://github.com/seperman/deepdiff

It deals with more than just recursive dictionary differences:

### Installation

Install from PyPi:

```
pip install deepdiff
```

If you are Python3 you need to also install:

```
pip install future six
```

### Example usage

```
>>> from deepdiff import DeepDiff
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> from __future__ import print_function
```

Same object returns empty

```
>>> t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3}
>>> t2 = t1
>>> ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2)
>>> print (ddiff.changes)
    {}
```

Type of an item has changed

```
>>> t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3}
>>> t2 = {1:1, 2:"2", 3:3}
>>> ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2)
>>> print (ddiff.changes)
    {'type_changes': ["root[2]: 2=<type 'int'> vs. 2=<type 'str'>"]}
```

Value of an item has changed

```
>>> t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3}
>>> t2 = {1:1, 2:4, 3:3}
>>> ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2)
>>> print (ddiff.changes)
    {'values_changed': ['root[2]: 2 ====>> 4']}
```

Item added and/or removed

```
>>> t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4}
>>> t2 = {1:1, 2:4, 3:3, 5:5, 6:6}
>>> ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2)
>>> pprint (ddiff.changes)
    {'dic_item_added': ['root[5, 6]'],
     'dic_item_removed': ['root[4]'],
     'values_changed': ['root[2]: 2 ====>> 4']}
```

String difference

```
>>> t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":"world"}}
>>> t2 = {1:1, 2:4, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":"world!"}}
>>> ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2)
>>> pprint (ddiff.changes, indent = 2)
    { 'values_changed': [ 'root[2]: 2 ====>> 4',
                          "root[4]['b']:\n--- \n+++ \n@@ -1 +1 @@\n-world\n+world!"]}
>>>
>>> print (ddiff.changes['values_changed'][1])
    root[4]['b']:
    --- 
    +++ 
    @@ -1 +1 @@
    -world
    +world!
```

String difference 2

```
>>> t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":"world!\nGoodbye!\n1\n2\nEnd"}}
>>> t2 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":"world\n1\n2\nEnd"}}
>>> ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2)
>>> pprint (ddiff.changes, indent = 2)
    { 'values_changed': [ "root[4]['b']:\n--- \n+++ \n@@ -1,5 +1,4 @@\n-world!\n-Goodbye!\n+world\n 1\n 2\n End"]}
>>>
>>> print (ddiff.changes['values_changed'][0])
    root[4]['b']:
    --- 
    +++ 
    @@ -1,5 +1,4 @@
    -world!
    -Goodbye!
    +world
     1
     2
     End
```

Type change

```
>>> t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":[1, 2, 3]}}
>>> t2 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":"world\n\n\nEnd"}}
>>> ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2)
>>> pprint (ddiff.changes, indent = 2)
    { 'type_changes': [ "root[4]['b']: [1, 2, 3]=<type 'list'> vs. world\n\n\nEnd=<type 'str'>"]}
```

List difference

```
>>> t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":[1, 2, 3]}}
>>> t2 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":[1, 2]}}
>>> ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2)
>>> pprint (ddiff.changes, indent = 2)
    { 'list_removed': ["root[4]['b']: [3]"]}
```

List difference 2: Note that it DOES NOT take order into account

```
>>> # Note that it DOES NOT take order into account
... t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":[1, 2, 3]}}
>>> t2 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":[1, 3, 2]}}
>>> ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2)
>>> pprint (ddiff.changes, indent = 2)
    { }
```

List that contains dictionary:

```
>>> t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":[1, 2, {1:1, 2:2}]}}
>>> t2 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":[1, 2, {1:3}]}}
>>> ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2)
>>> pprint (ddiff.changes, indent = 2)
    { 'dic_item_removed': ["root[4]['b'][2][2]"],
      'values_changed': ["root[4]['b'][2][1]: 1 ====>> 3"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple solution. It returns a list of lists containing all the first and second level dictionary keys for the elements that differ. Hope that is what you wanted :)

```
a = {'home':{'name': 'Team1', 'score': 0}, 'away':{'name': 'Team2', 'score': 0}}
b = {'home':{'name': 'Team1', 'score': 2}, 'away':{'name': 'Team2', 'score': 0}}

diffs = []
for i in a:
    for j in a[i]:
        if a[i][j] != b[i][j]:
            diffs += [i, j]

print diffs
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you need but i've found a library which produces the diff between python data structures. It's called [datadiff](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/datadiff/1.1.4) and it fives you all the different enries between two dictionaries. i'm not sure nether if it gives you the difference in "store", maybe it will show a different value for the whole "home" entry. You have to try it.