# Setting the property of a property

Tags: python, properties

I am trying to figure out a way of having the setter of a property of a property trigger some action on the top level class.

As a dummy example, lets say my top level class is a `Segment`. All is good if I store the coordinates of its endpoints directly as properties of this object `x0`, `y0`, `x1` and `y1`, and have the setters of each one trigger the selected action.

But if I want to group them into two `Point` members as properties `p0` and `p1`, each with properties `x` and `y`, whenever one of these coordinates is modified, there is no obvious way of telling the `Segment` to do something. This is what I would like to be able to do:

```
>>> segment = Segment(Point(0, 0), Point(3, 3))
>>> segment.p0
Point(0, 0)
>>> segment.p0.x
0
>>> segment.p1.y = 4
Length of segment changed to 5.0!  # This can only be printed by segment, not p1!
```

The problem is that the line `segment.p1.y = 4` first calls the getter of `p1` on the `segment` instance, and then the setter of `y` on the return of the previous call, at which point there is no simple way of letting the `segment` instance know that a change has been made.

The best I can think of right now is something along the lines of the following:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, parent=None, name=None):
        self.parent, self.name = parent, name
        self._x, self._y = x, y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x
    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value
        if parent is not None:
            setattr(self.parent, self.name, self)

    # Similar code for y goes here...


class Segment(object):
    def __init__(self, p0, p1):
        self.p0, self.p1 = p0, p1

    @property
    def p0(self):
        return self._p0
    @p0.setter
    def p0(self, point):
        self._p0 = point
        self.p0.parent = self
        self.p0.name = 'p0'
        if not self._silent:
            self.do_something()  # This would print the length in the above example

    # Similar code for p1 goes here...
```

While this does what I want it to, I don't quite like having to manually add that link back to the parent, nor how I would either have to make lots of redundant copies of the `Point` objects, or risk interesting bugs if doing something like:

```
p0, p1, p2 = Point(0, 0), Point(1, 1), Point(2, 2)
seg0 = Segment(p0, p1)
seg1 = Segment(p0, p2)
# The following line changes the value on both seg0 and seg1, but triggers
# the do_something call on seg1 only!
seg0.p0.x = 6
```

Is there some ready-made recipe for this? Anyone can come up with a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for the [Observer design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/715314/190597):

```
import math

class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, name=None):
        self.name = name
        self._x, self._y = x, y
        self.observers = []

    def observe(self, observer):
        self.observers.append(observer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Point({}, {})'.format(self.x, self.y)

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x
    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value
        for o in self.observers:
            o.notify()

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y
    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self._y = value
        for o in self.observers:
            o.notify()

class Segment(object):
    def __init__(self, p0, p1):
        self._p0, self._p1 = p0, p1
        p0.observe(self)
        p1.observe(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Segment({}, {})'.format(self.p0, self.p1)

    def notify(self):
        print('Length of {} changed to {}'.format(self, self.length()))

    def length(self):
        return math.sqrt((self.p0.x - self.p1.x)**2
                         + (self.p0.y - self.p1.y)**2)

    @property
    def p0(self):
        return self._p0
    @p0.setter
    def p0(self, point):
        self._p0 = point

    @property
    def p1(self):
        return self._p1
    @p1.setter
    def p1(self, point):
        self._p1 = point
```

---

```
segment = Segment(Point(0, 0), Point(3, 3))
print(segment.p0)
# Point(0, 0)
print(segment.p0.x)
# 0
segment.p1.y = 4
```

yields

```
Length of Segment(Point(0, 0), Point(3, 4)) changed to 5.0
```

and

```
p0, p1, p2 = Point(0, 0), Point(1, 1), Point(2, 2)
seg0 = Segment(p0, p1)
seg1 = Segment(p0, p2)
seg0.p0.x = 6
```

yields

```
Length of Segment(Point(6, 0), Point(1, 1)) changed to 5.09901951359
Length of Segment(Point(6, 0), Point(2, 2)) changed to 4.472135955
```

Comment: That certainly looks like what I am after, thanks! Time to revisit the GOF book, this time actually paying attention to it...